# Tricky layout with ViewPager and PopupWindow

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-popupwindow

I'm trying to implement the following miniplayer for a music player: [ui gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiNZJ.jpg)

I currently have a vertical view pager that is slightly taller than one card/song. It's populated with miniplayer fragments via a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I now have most of the vertical scrolling behavior I want but as expected, the top of the miniplayer is clipped by the layout bounds of the ViewPager. This led me to look into [`PopupWindow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html).

I'm currently trying to implement the fading away effect as seen in the gif. I'm using a `PopupWindow` so that miniplayer views can be seen outside the view bounds of the vertical viewpager. I tried putting the views from the fragment in the PopupWindow but I got an IllegalStateException because the view already had a parent (which was the VerticalViewPager). I'm now inflating a dummy view that looks exactly like the Miniplayer, but instead of returning it in onCreateView, that's the view I use in the PopupWindow's constructor. I then call

```
 mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(contentView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
```

I think I should be passing the TouchEvents from the real miniplayer view in order to translate the dummy view vertically past the bounds of the viewpager, but I'm a little stuck because the real view is showing underneath and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Am I going down the right path (implementation wise)?